# Performance OpenMP collapse vs no collapse for large nested loops

Tags: c, openmp

I was wondering if anyone knows a bid more about the perfomance of the collapse cause for large nested loops?
Meaning I would like to compare the pragmas

`omp parallel for private(i,j,k) collapse(3) schedule(static)`

and

`omp parallel for private(i,j,k) schedule(static)`

for a nested loop construct like

```
for(int i=0; i<i_max; i++){
  for(int j=0; j<j_max; j++){
   for(int k=0; k<k_max; k++){
     A[i][j][k]=B[i][j][k]+C[i][j][k];
                              }
                             }
                            }
```

where i_max, j_max and k_max are all something like 5 - 10 times larger than the number of threads available.

If I understood the collapse cause correctly openmp would just collapse the 3 loops into one having the size `i_max*j_max*k_max`and I would assume best perfomance if `(i_max*j_max*k_max) mod #threads = 0`.

Is it right that without the collapse cause openmp would only take the i loop parallel? If so my next assumption would be to get the best perfomance for `i_max mod #threads = 0` and I would expect comparable performances for both pragmas.

As you can see I am pretty much guessing here. Did anyone actually test the performance of both pragmas for cases such as this?

Comment: Your guesses are fine. Did *you* test performance for both cases?

Comment: For loops with such small bodies the non-collapsed version could be faster (how much? _it depends_) when the number of threads divides `i_max` due to better implementation of the inner loops. Collapsing the loops might inhibit their vectorisation.

Comment: @Zulan I did some testing but wasn't sure how to interpret my results. On one server the collapse version was faster and on another the non collapse version. Came here for some clarification 'cause I don't have the server capacity to test it extensivly without inhibiting some simulations.

Comment: @Hristo Might be a bid off topic, but could you explain to me how openmp influences the vectorisation in both cases? And could you maybe go a little bid more into detail about your "it depends"? Will mark that as the answer then.

Comment: When you include the inner loop in collapse and don't set simd you are suggesting you don't want vectorizaton  gcc would probably treat simd as not set anyway. If you don't set collapse, the compiler would have freedom to switch inner loops to optimize vectorization.

Comment: @tim18 Okay.. So I guess it settles to the non collapse version being faster in general due to better optimized vectorization as Hristo also mentioned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you collapse the loops, OpenMP turns them into one big loop. The iteration space of that loop then gets divided into chunks and those get split among the threads according to the effective loop schedule. Depending on the divisibility of the individual loop iterations by the number of threads, you might end up in a situation where a chunk contains incomplete inner loops. An example case would be when none of `i_max`, `j_max`, and `k_max` is divisible by the number of threads, but `i_max * j_max * k_max` is. Moreover, different chunks might contain different parts of the incomplete loops. And then this all depends on the run-time configurable number of threads. So the vectoriser might be inhibited as the compiler is unable to reliably model the vectorisation of the loop and evaluate whether it will be beneficial or not. It will also have to create serial loops that handle the case when the number of loop iterations is not divisible by the vector length or the data is not aligned.

When only the outer loop is parallel, the compiler is free to transform the inner loops as it sees fit, e.g., it could safely vectorise those loops. Whether that will be faster than the previous case is not clear. Vectorisation improves computational performance, but it also puts more pressure on the memory subsystem. The ratio of those determines if there will be a benefit.

On the other hand, assuming that `A`, `B`, and `C` are all `i_max` x `j_max` x `k_max` (and that `x <= x_max` is a typo and should actually be `x < x_max`), a really smart compiler will notice that you are iterating over all possible indices and basically summing two 1-D vectors and turn the collapsed loop into something like

```
#pragma omp parallel schedule(static)
for (z = 0; z < i_max * j_max * k_max; z++)
   A_lin[z] = B_lin[z] + C_lin[z];
```

where `X_lin[]` is the linearised 1-D view of the data behind `X[][][]`. There is a great potential for vectorisation here, so it really depends on how much analysis the compiler is able to perform.

There is no silver bullet solution and no one algorithm that performs equally good across many types of hardware. That's why OpenMP provides a lot of tunables that can be set via environment variables. Also note that when comparing the performance on a server CPU and a desktop CPU, one should keep in mind that server CPUs usually have much larger last-level caches and more memory channels with higher main memory bandwidth, so vectorised codes perform better on large amounts of data.

Comment: Yes the '<='  were typos!
Thank you for your elaborate answer!

Comment: "Depending on the divisibility of the individual loop iterations by the number of threads, you might end up in a situation where a chunk contains incomplete inner loops"...

Finding this out the hard way